# Getting a file, copying that file, then creating a folder, then pasting that file in the created folder

Tags: excel, vba

So basically, I need to transfer pdf file from one folder to another. But the source folder contains thousands of pdfs and i need to transfer about 500+ of them in another folder which I should create as well. So it means, I copy "apple" from source then in the destination folder, I'll create a folder named "apple" then paste the copied "apple" file in the created "apple" folder.

```
Sub transferpdf()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Stress Log").Activate
r = 3
'Declare Variables
'Do While Cells(r, 3) <> ""
Dim FSO
Dim sFile As String
Dim sSFolder As String
Dim sDFolder As String
Dim foldname As String
Call create_folder

'Name of new folder
'foldname = Cells(r, 1)
'File name to copy
sFile = Cells(r, 3) & "_R" & Cells(r, 4) & ".pdf"

'Source file path
sSFolder = "\\Fdnet.com\ca_projects\CA_LNGC\000_GENERAL\TRANSFER\TO CSA_From Stress  - PERMANENT\"

'Destination file path
sDFolder = "C:\Users\vid14865\Desktop\VLM - Sir Earl\3RC430BB VLM - Stress ISOs\" & foldname

'Create Object
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Checking If File Is Located in the Source Folder
If Not FSO.FileExists(sSFolder & sFile) Then
    MsgBox [sFile] & " Not Found", vbInformation, "Not Found"

'Copying If the Same File is Not Located in the Destination Folder
ElseIf Not FSO.FileExists(sDFolder & sFile) Then
    FSO.CopyFile (sSFolder & sFile), sDFolder, True
    MsgBox [sFile] & (" Copied Successfully")

Else
    MsgBox [sFile] & " Already Exists In The Destination Folder", vbExclamation, "File Already Exists"
End If
'r = r + 1
'Loop
MsgBox "Finished Creating"
End Sub
Sub create_folder()
Sheets("Stress Log").Activate
r = 3
foldname = Cells(r, 1)
MkDir ("C:\Users\vid14865\Desktop\VLM - Sir Earl\3RC430BB VLM - Stress ISOs\" & foldname)

End Sub
```

This is what I have so far. This creates the folder and copies the file very well, but then the file is not copied in the folder. It's copied outside the created file.

[image]

Comment: by the way i removed that loop first since it will be easy to incorporate that when the main code's been fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Does `sDFolder` end with a backslash? It needs to. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/copyfile-method

Comment: foldname is not automatically passed to the first code, you could create the folder in the first code instead of calling the macro. what if you uncomment   `'foldname = Cells(r, 1)`